# Yii2 suggestion for two or more users

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-user, yii2-rbac

I'm beginner to yii2, I want to FOLLOW a suggermento Which way to create two users with different capabilities. Can you give me an example of how to create two types of users? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yii2 for manage the proces for verifying that a user has enough permission to do somethingthere there are ACF and RBAC

ACF Access Control Filter  is a simple authorization method implemented and  is best used by applications that only need some simple access control.

RBAC Role-Based Access Control provides a  powerful centralized access control yet simple to mnanage.

Yii implements a General Hierarchical RBAC, following the NIST RBAC model.

RBAC can be based on PHP files or directly on database table ..

you can find useful info in this guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Answer (score 1):

Please folow yii2 starter kit for reference RBAC config. With feature RBAC with predefined guest, user, manager and administrator roles.
[Yii2 starter kit](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use user roles and give specific permissions to each of roles

Comment: You mean by RBAC Rules?

Comment: you can not create two types of users?

Comment: Yes with RBAC you can also add optional fields to each role with pivot table